# PHP7 - uploading file not showing _FILES array

Tags: php, nginx

When uploading a file and printing `$_FILES` variable I get this

`print_r($_FILES);`

```
Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 20130919_125158.jpg
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                )

            [t
```

`var_dump($_FILES);`

```
array(1) {
  ["files"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "d.jpg"
    }
    ["type"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "image/jpeg"
    }
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "/t
```

Not all variables are printed? The last part of the array is missing..

I can't access `$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0]`

Some uploaded files gives all parameters - some doesn't

Nothing to see in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

```
2016/04/06 10:17:13 [warn] 29377#29377: *13009 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/client_temp/0000000026, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: host, request: "POST /da/api/action/upload_voucher/ HTTP/1.1", host: "host", referrer: "http://host"
```

And no PHP errors either

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: Could you give some more details?

Comment: Have added more information

Comment: try `var_dump($_FILES)` instead of `print_f`

Comment: It seems that the file upload was fine. Can you  `echo $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][0]`? Can you `file_exists($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][0])`?